# Div move after click on another div using angular js

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html, css

I implement a DRAG and DROP Angularjs for my project to move a DIV from one location to another location in order to let the user able to categorize the items. I just need to fulfill my simple requirement namely:

```
Step 1: User click at division (1) 
Step 2: User click at division (2)
```

**Process will be taken:**
*Once user at  **STEP(2)**, the **`Goose`** will move to **`STEP (2)`**. If user click once again `Goose` in **`STEP(2)`** then it will go back to **`STEP(1)`**.*

How I can do that?

*As you can see my expected output:*

[image]

My current codes so far:

```js
var myApp = angular.module('MyApp',['ngDraggable']).controller('MyCtrl',function($scope){
  
    $scope.centerAnchor = true;
    $scope.toggleCenterAnchor = function () {
        $scope.centerAnchor = !$scope.centerAnchor
    };

    var onDraggableEvent = function (evt, data) {
        console.log("128", "onDraggableEvent", evt, data);
    };
    $scope.$on('draggable:start', onDraggableEvent);
    $scope.$on('draggable:end', onDraggableEvent);
    $scope.droppedObjects0 = [{name:'Goose'},{name:'Rabbit'},{name:'Chick'},{name:'Cat'}];
    $scope.droppedObjects1 = []; //Answer: Cat + Rabbit
    $scope.droppedObjects2 = []; //Answer: Chicken + Goose
    
    
    $scope.AnswerOject1 = [{name:'Arnab'},{name:'Kucing'}];
    $scope.AnswerOject2 = [{name:'Angsa'},{name:'Ayam'}];
    
    $scope.onDropComplete0 = function (data, evt) {
        console.log("127", "$scope", "onDropComplete0", data, evt);
        var index = $scope.droppedObjects0.indexOf(data);
        if (index == -1)
            $scope.droppedObjects0.push(data);
    };
    $scope.onDropComplete1 = function (data, evt) {
        console.log("127", "$scope", "onDropComplete1", data, evt);
        var index = $scope.droppedObjects1.indexOf(data);
        if (index == -1)
            $scope.droppedObjects1.push(data);
    };
    $scope.onDragSuccess0 = function (data, evt) {
        console.log("133", "$scope", "onDragSuccess0", "", evt);
        var index = $scope.droppedObjects0.indexOf(data);
        if (index > -1) {
            $scope.droppedObjects0.splice(index, 1);
        }
    };
    $scope.onDragSuccess1 = function (data, evt) {
        console.log("133", "$scope", "onDragSuccess1", "", evt);
        var index = $scope.droppedObjects1.indexOf(data);
        if (index > -1) {
            $scope.droppedObjects1.splice(index, 1);
        }
    };
    $scope.onDragSuccess2 = function (data, evt) {
        var index = $scope.droppedObjects2.indexOf(data);
        if (index > -1) {
            $scope.droppedObjects2.splice(index, 1);
        }
    };
    $scope.onDropComplete2 = function (data, evt) {
        var index = $scope.droppedObjects2.indexOf(data);
        if (index == -1) {
            $scope.droppedObjects2.push(data);
        }
    };
    var inArray = function (array, obj) {
        var index = array.indexOf(obj);
    };
});
```

```css
.body
{
    width:500px;
    margin-left:auto; 
    margin-right:auto;
}

[ng-drag] {
    -moz-user-select: -moz-none;
    -khtml-user-select: none;
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    -ms-user-select: none;
    user-select: none;
}

[ng-drag] {
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);
    color: #131313;
    text-align: center;
    padding-top: 12px;
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 5px 5px;
    cursor: move;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    border-radius: 4px;
}

ul.draggable-objects:after {
    display: block;
    content: "";
    clear: both;
}

.draggable-objects li {
    float: left;
    display: block;
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    margin:2px;
}

[ng-drag].drag-over {
    border: solid 1px red;
}

[ng-drag].dragging {
    opacity: 0.5;
}

[ng-drop] {
    background: rgba(198, 255, 198, 0.5);
    text-align: center;
    height: 150px;
    padding-top: 10px;
    display: block;
    margin: 20px auto;
    position: relative;
    border: 1px solid #c3c3c3;
    border-radius: 8px;
}

[ng-drop].drag-enter {
    border: solid 5px red;
}

[ng-drop] span.title {
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    width: 200px;
    height: 20px;
    margin-left: -100px;
    margin-top: -10px;
}

[ng-drop] div {
    position: relative;
    z-index: 2;
}
.list-of-drag-item
{
    height: 83px;
    background-color: #f7f7f7;
}
```

```html
<link href="http://code.ionicframework.com/1.3.1/css/ionic.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ngDraggable/0.1.10/ngDraggable.js"></script>

<div ng-app="MyApp" ng-controller="MyCtrl" class="body">
Categorize the animals based on their reproductive system
<div class="row">
    <div class="col">
        <div class="list-of-drag-item" ng-drop="true" ng-drop-success="onDropComplete0($data,$event)">
            <div ng-click="clickMe()"  ng-repeat="obj in droppedObjects0" ng-drag="true" ng-drag-data="obj"
                ng-drag-success="onDragSuccess0($data,$event)" ng-center-anchor="{{centerAnchor}}">
               {{obj.name}}
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="row" style="text-align: center;">
    <div class="col div-left">
        <span class="title">Animals that give birth
        <div ng-drop="true" ng-drop-success="onDropComplete1($data,$event)">
            <div ng-repeat="obj in droppedObjects1" ng-drag="true" ng-drag-data="obj"
                 ng-drag-success="onDragSuccess1($data,$event)" ng-center-anchor="{{centerAnchor}}">
                {{obj.name}}
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col div-right">
        <span class="title">Animals that Laying Eggs</span>
        <div ng-drop="true" ng-drop-success="onDropComplete2($data,$event)">
            <div ng-repeat="obj in droppedObjects2" ng-drag="true" ng-drag-data="obj"
                 ng-drag-success="onDragSuccess2($data,$event)" ng-center-anchor="{{centerAnchor}}">
                {{obj.name}}
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
  </div>
```

Comment: I'm sorry but I don't get exactly what you would like to do. Could you try to explain it in some more detail?

Comment: User at first click `Goose` then click at below DIV, the `Goose` will move to that DIV.

Comment: Oh, ok! Thanks for the clarification.

Comment: Just a note-- [ngDraggable](https://github.com/fatlinesofcode/ngDraggable#ngdraggable) is no currently being maintained by its authors per the documentation-- and it has 64 open issues.  You may be better looking for a different library, or maybe just going native.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I changed your code to achieve this. First, you haven´t checked if there is an object on your drop event handlers and the drop event is fired if you just click on an element. Must be a bug in the drag&drop library.
Then i added click handlers on the elements for saving the given reference in `$scope.activeElement` and their containers reference in `containerOfActiveElement`. Also there are click handlers on the containers for adding and removing the active element from the container arrays.

There is also some code in the template and css for setting a red background on the active element. It also adds a transition which, in combination with angulars `$timeout`, makes the animation happen.

You have a lot of duplicated code. You could improve that with passing the array references like i did.

```js
var myApp = angular.module('MyApp', ['ngDraggable']).controller('MyCtrl',function($scope, $timeout){

$scope.activeElement;
var containerOfActiveElement;
var activeHTMLElement;
var getCenterOfELement = function (htmlElement) {
  var rect = htmlElement.getBoundingClientRect(); 
  return {
    x: rect.left + rect.width / 2,
    y: rect.top + rect.height / 2
  }
};
$scope.onElementClick = function(event, data, container) {
  if (!angular.equals(data, $scope.activeElement)) {
    event.stopPropagation(); // you need this for not firing event on container
    $scope.activeElement = data;
    containerOfActiveElement = container;
    activeHTMLElement = event.target;
  } else 
    $scope.activeElement = null;
};
$scope.onTargetClick = function(container, event) {
  if ($scope.activeElement) {
    var activeCenter = getCenterOfELement(activeHTMLElement);
    var targetCenter = getCenterOfELement(event.target);
    var offsetX = targetCenter.x - activeCenter.x;
    var offsetY = targetCenter.y - activeCenter.y;
    activeHTMLElement.style.transform= 'translate('+offsetX+'px,'+offsetY+'px)';
    $timeout(function() {
        container.push($scope.activeElement);
        var index = containerOfActiveElement.indexOf($scope.activeElement);
        containerOfActiveElement.splice(index, 1);
        $scope.activeElement = null;
        containerOfActiveElement = null; 
        activeHTMLElement = null;
    }, 200);
  }
};
  
$scope.centerAnchor = true;
$scope.toggleCenterAnchor = function () {
    $scope.centerAnchor = !$scope.centerAnchor
};

/* can be removed, since it has no effect:
var onDraggableEvent = function (evt, data) {
    console.log("128", "onDraggableEvent", evt, data);
};
$scope.$on('draggable:start', onDraggableEvent);
$scope.$on('draggable:end', onDraggableEvent);
*/
  
$scope.droppedObjects0 = [{name:'Goose'},{name:'Rabbit'},{name:'Chick'},{name:'Cat'}];
$scope.droppedObjects1 = []; //Answer: Cat + Rabbit
$scope.droppedObjects2 = []; //Answer: Chicken + Goose


$scope.AnswerOject1 = [{name:'Arnab'},{name:'Kucing'}];
$scope.AnswerOject2 = [{name:'Angsa'},{name:'Ayam'}];

$scope.onDropComplete0 = function (data, evt) {
    console.log("127", "$scope", "onDropComplete0", data, evt);
    var index = $scope.droppedObjects0.indexOf(data);
    if (index == -1 && data !== null) // gave unwanted result if data was null (new empty object)
        $scope.droppedObjects0.push(data);
};
$scope.onDropComplete1 = function (data, evt) {
    console.log("127", "$scope", "onDropComplete1", data, evt);
    var index = $scope.droppedObjects0.indexOf(data);
    if (index == -1 && data !== null)
        $scope.droppedObjects1.push(data);
};
$scope.onDragSuccess0 = function (data, evt) {
    console.log("133", "$scope", "onDragSuccess0", "", evt);
    var index = $scope.droppedObjects0.indexOf(data);
    if (index > -1 && data) {
        $scope.droppedObjects0.splice(index, 1);
    }
};
$scope.onDragSuccess1 = function (data, evt) {
    console.log("133", "$scope", "onDragSuccess1", "", evt);
    var index = $scope.droppedObjects1.indexOf(data);
    if (index > -1) {
        $scope.droppedObjects1.splice(index, 1);
    }
};
$scope.onDragSuccess2 = function (data, evt) {
    var index = $scope.droppedObjects2.indexOf(data);
    if (index > -1) {
        $scope.droppedObjects2.splice(index, 1);
    }
};
$scope.onDropComplete2 = function (data, evt) {
    var index = $scope.droppedObjects2.indexOf(data);
    if (index == -1 && data !== null) {
        $scope.droppedObjects2.push(data);
    }
};
var inArray = function (array, obj) {
    var index = array.indexOf(obj);
};
$scope.logResults = function() {
     console.log({
        'div1': $scope.droppedObjects0,
        'div2': $scope.droppedObjects1,
        'div3': $scope.droppedObjects2
     });
}
});
```

```css
.body
{
    width:500px;
    margin-left:auto; 
    margin-right:auto;
}

[ng-drag] {
    -moz-user-select: -moz-none;
    -khtml-user-select: none;
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    -ms-user-select: none;
    user-select: none;
}

[ng-drag] {
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);
    color: #131313;
    text-align: center;
    padding-top: 12px;
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 5px 5px;
    cursor: move;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    border-radius: 4px;
}

ul.draggable-objects:after {
    display: block;
    content: "";
    clear: both;
}

.draggable-objects li {
    float: left;
    display: block;
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    margin:2px;
}

[ng-drag].drag-over {
    border: solid 1px red;
}

[ng-drag].dragging {
    opacity: 0.5;
}

[ng-drop] {
    background: rgba(198, 255, 198, 0.5);
    text-align: center;
    height: 150px;
    padding-top: 10px;
    display: block;
    margin: 20px auto;
    position: relative;
    border: 1px solid #c3c3c3;
    border-radius: 8px;
}

[ng-drop].drag-enter {
    border: solid 5px red;
}

[ng-drop] span.title {
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    width: 200px;
    height: 20px;
    margin-left: -100px;
    margin-top: -10px;
}

[ng-drop] div {
    position: relative;
    z-index: 2;
}
.list-of-drag-item
{
    height: 83px;
    background-color: #f7f7f7;
}

.active {
    background-color: red;
    color: white;
    transition: transform .2s ease-in-out;
}
```

```html
<link href="http://code.ionicframework.com/1.3.1/css/ionic.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
   <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
   <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script>
   <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ngDraggable/0.1.10/ngDraggable.js"></script>

<div ng-app="MyApp" ng-controller="MyCtrl" class="body">
    Categorize the animals based on their reproductive system
<div class="row">
<div class="col">
    <div class="list-of-drag-item" ng-drop="true" ng-drop-success="onDropComplete0($data,$event)" ng-click="onTargetClick(droppedObjects0, $event)">
        <div ng-click="onElementClick($event, obj, droppedObjects0)"  ng-repeat="obj in droppedObjects0" ng-drag="true" ng-drag-data="obj"
            ng-drag-success="onDragSuccess0($data,$event)" ng-center-anchor="{{centerAnchor}}" ng-class="{active: activeElement.name === obj.name}">
           {{obj.name}}
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
<div class="row" style="text-align: center;">
<div class="col div-left">
    <span class="title">Animals that give birth
    <div ng-drop="true" ng-drop-success="onDropComplete1($data,$event)" ng-click="onTargetClick(droppedObjects1, $event)">
        <div ng-repeat="obj in droppedObjects1" ng-drag="true" ng-drag-data="obj" ng-drag-success="onDragSuccess1($data,$event)" ng-center-anchor="{{centerAnchor}}" ng-click="onElementClick($event, obj, droppedObjects1)" ng-class="{active: activeElement.name === obj.name}">
            {{obj.name}}
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="col div-right">
    <span class="title">Animals that Laying Eggs</span>
    <div ng-drop="true" ng-drop-success="onDropComplete2($data,$event)" ng-click="onTargetClick(droppedObjects2, $event)">
        <div ng-repeat="obj in droppedObjects2" ng-drag="true" ng-drag-data="obj"
             ng-drag-success="onDragSuccess2($data,$event)" ng-center-anchor="{{centerAnchor}}" ng-click="onElementClick($event, obj, droppedObjects2)" ng-class="{active: activeElement.name === obj.name}">
            {{obj.name}}
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
   <button ng-click="logResults()">log results</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Very good! If you can do animation during box change location then it would be excellent! One more..can you show me the data returned in JSON type?eg [{DIV:1,[{"CHICK","GOOSE"}]]

Comment: Here you go, i added an animation and also a button which log your state.

Comment: I'll leave your answer for 5 days. You have exactly answered my question. Thank you very much!

Comment: @Imran if your question was exactly answered, why don't you mark it as such and release the respective bounty?